# How to solve "/usr/bin/ld: cannot -lodbcinst" problem during FreeTDS installation

Tags: rhel, opensource-projects, database

I have installed unixodbc for Microsoft SQL Server support in Linux. I want to connect PHP on Linux to a MS SQL server. I tried to install FreeTDS opensource , but it gives me following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot -lodbcinst
```

What is best way to install FreeTDS?

Comment: Your question lacks some information. What is your linux distribution ? have you installed odbc ? from a package system ? what are your ./configure options ?

Comment: Yes I have installed unixodbc

and installed freetds by following way

[root@localhost]# tar xvfz freetds-0.60.tgz
[root@localhost]# cd freetds-0.60
[root@localhost]# ./configure --with-tdsver=7.0 --with-unixodbc
[root@localhost]# make
[root@localhost]# make install
[root@localhost]# make clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your rhel tag, I guess that you are using a Red Hat system.

This error message tells you that you need a file named libodbcinst.a or libodbcinst.so. FreeTDS needs to link to it in order to work properly.

On Red Hat System, [pbone says](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=1&srodzaj=1&dl=40&search=libodbcinst.so&field%5B%5D=1&field%5B%5D=2) that you need to install [unixODBC-devel](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17012718/dir/centos_5/com/unixODBC-devel-2.2.11-7.1.x86_64.rpm.html) via your package system, if you want to pursue your manual installation. But you can also use the already packaged FreeTDS, which seems [available for RHEL 5 & 6](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=1&srodzaj=3&dl=40&search=freeTDS).

Comment: Finally connected to sql server. problem in my configuration files. I solved by putting proper values. Thanks for supporting

Comment: @Abhijeet : you're welcome. Can you check this question as answered, plz ?